# How can I know if a user in session filled an upgrade form?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

I am building a nodejs application where a user can change roles by filling a new form while in session. How do I know which user has filled the upgrade form. To rephrase, how do I link an upgrade to the user who filled the upgrade form.

I currently have this schema for a user

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose"

const basicRegSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    match: /.+\@.+\..+/,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  user_role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["user","campaign responder", "campaigner creator"],
    default: "user"
  },

});

basicRegSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {usernameField: "email"});
const NewReg = mongoose.model("NewReg", basicRegSchema);


export default NewReg;
```

Comment: How do you identify the user/session?! The same way.

Comment: @Marc I beg your pardon the only way I know to identify a user is to retrieve from the database. And i believe that is the gap in my knowledge which is why I am asking the question in the first place. If you would give me more hints. Thanks

Comment: Ok, where does "a user can change roles by filling a new form" happen? Is this a http request or what? When it is in fact related to http, then who do you know which user has filled the form? You not create a bonding between session&user. So you know when a user performs a operation agains your service. If you know that, then you have answerd your own question :)

Comment: Yes definitely an http request. And that is exactly what i need to know "how to create a bonding between session and user so i can know if a **particular** user has submitted a form" @Marc thanks for your time

Comment: I would do that on the login/auth setup. When the user login, set a cookie/session with its email/username/id or whatever. Now, the browser sends with every http requestion to your site all needed informations. I dont like sessions exactly for that, i use JWTs or other auth stuff.

Comment: I do have login auth and session.id already set up. But when the user fills the form and send to the server does the server links the form data to the user session id? @Marc